# Multiple versions of same Python package in same Conda

Tags: python, package, conda

Have multiple python projects ( build into wheel packages ) that should work together under the same Conda environment. For example projects A, B

Both of them use another package C BUT of a different version. Also A reference B

```
B --> C 1.0.x

A --> C 2.0.x , B
```

Versions of the referenced package are incompatible.
I also can't upgrade them to the newest available version, because versions are pinned and shouldn't be changed.

What is the best solution to go in this situation ?

Comment: Create 2 different environments for each app. Rude but true, if you have an application with multiple parts of conflicting requirements, you need to split and wire them together - a.k.a microservices.

Comment: This is exactly the way I thought, but I asked this because it's rude and maybe something else exists that I am still not informed about.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe or want to achieve is not possible. If A and B must exist in the same env,  then they MUST have compatible requirement of package C. Some of the restrictions in your descriptions will have to give in, either:

- A and B will not be able to work together OR
- you change B so that it can work with `C==2.0`
- you change A to be compatible with `C==1.0`

Comment: You are right, this is exactly the question. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why can't conda allow the user to install two versions of C, and let A and B to choose the version of C they want?

Comment: Take the example of python packages. You cannot have two separate versions of let's say `numpy ` in the same env, because every script importing it will jsut have `import numpy`. There is no logic to choose one version or the other. Additionally, both versions would want to reside in `site-packages\numpy`, so there is a clash of file locations